# simple JavaScript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I just wanted to trigger an alert function when I click some HTML tags.

```
# app/assets/javascripts/home.js

function alertBox() {
  window.alert("gogo");
}
document.getElementById("java-test").onclick = function() { alertBox() };


# app/views/home/index.html.erb

<h1>please <span id="java-test">pop</span> up~</h1>
```

It's working when I use `<span onclick="alertBox()">` but I just wanted to make the HTML files a little bit clearer. What am I missing?

I think I'm totally wrong on understanding how it works on Ruby on Rails. Any of your comments would be a huge help to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your DOM isn't ready, so your span isn't there for the script to find when it does `getElementById`. Try this, instead:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/home.js

function alertBox() {
  window.alert("gogo");
}
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("java-test").onclick = function() {
        alertBox();
    };
};


# app/views/home/index.html.erb

<h1>please <span id="java-test">pop</span> up~</h1>
```

Comment: It works when I changed `document.onload` to `window.onload`.(maybe there is some time lags between window and document?) But I didn't know that DOM isn't ready for the function. Thank you!

Comment: @JeongbinKim Sorry, it should be `window.onload`, not `document.onload`. That was a mistake, which I have fixed. I'm glad this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#java-test").click(function() {
    alert("Hi there!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @jmargolisvt!. My mistake might come from the ignorance that DOM should be ready before I can make the functions work.